# Execute a JOIN N times - possible in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, loops, join

Let's say I have a series of similar subqueries, and I want to join those subqueries N times.

For example, something like this:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 records
FOR i IN 1..N LOOP
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM records where records.id = i) as i::text
END LOOP
```

... which I know isn't valid. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using a dynamic query:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    r record;
    sql text;
    i integer;
BEGIN
    sql := 'SELECT * from records';

    FOR i IN 1..5 
    LOOP
        sql := sql || ' JOIN (SELECT * FROM records where records.id = ' || i || ')';

    END LOOP;
    RAISE INFO 'Query: %', sql;

   EXECUTE sql;
END$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

More simply:

```
SELECT * from records where id BETWEEN 1 and 10;
```

If you're doing something more complex you could use `generate_series` to generate your 1..*n* ids (*n* = 10 in this example):

```
SELECT *
FROM records r
  JOIN (SELECT generate_series(1, 10) id) s
  ON r.id = s.id;
```